# Properly formatted example for Python iMAP email access?

Tags: python, email, imap

tldr:  Can someone show me how to properly format this Python iMAP example so it works?

from 
https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/imap4-example.html

> ```
> import getpass, imaplib
>
> M = imaplib.IMAP4()
> M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
> M.select()
> typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
> for num in data[0].split():
>     typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
>     print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
> M.close()
> M.logout()
> ```

Assuming my email is "email@gmail.com" and the password is "password," how should this look?  I tried `M.login(getpass.getuser(email@gmail.com), getpass.getpass(password))`
and it timed out.  Complete newb here, so it's very likely I missed something obvious (like creating an iMAP object first?  Not sure).

Answer (score 11):

```
import imaplib

# you want to connect to a server; specify which server
server= imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.googlemail.com')
# after connecting, tell the server who you are
server.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
# this will show you a list of available folders
# possibly your Inbox is called INBOX, but check the list of mailboxes
code, mailboxen= server.list()
print mailboxen
# if it's called INBOX, then…
server.select("INBOX")
```

The rest of your code seems correct.

Comment: Just to save others time who might see this...it's "IMAP4_SSL" not just "IMAP_SSL".

Answer (score 11):

Here is a script I used to use to grab logwatch info from my mailbox. [Presented at LFNW 2008](http://brianlane.com/articles/lfnw2008/) -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Utility to scan my mailbox for new mesages from Logwatch on systems and then
    grab useful info from the message and output a summary page.

    by Brian C. Lane <bcl@brianlane.com>
'''
import os, sys, imaplib, rfc822, re, StringIO

server  ='mail.brianlane.com'
username='yourusername'
password='yourpassword'

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
M.login(username, password)
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, '(UNSEEN SUBJECT "Logwatch")')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
#   print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])

    match = re.search(  "^(Users logging in.*?)^\w",
                        data[0][1],
                        re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL )
    if match:
        file = StringIO.StringIO(data[0][1])
        message = rfc822.Message(file)
        print message['from']
        print match.group(1).strip()
        print '----'

M.close()
M.logout()
```

Comment: Caveat programmer: use of Python module "rfc822" has been deprecated since Python 2.3.  (Source: http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/rfc822.html)  Consider using email module, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to specify the IMAP host and port? Use something to the effect of:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL( 'imap.gmail.com' )
```

or,

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL()
M.open( 'imap.gmail.com' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `M.login(getpass.getuser(email@gmail.com), getpass.getpass(password))` you need to use `M.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')`, i.e. plain strings (or better, variables containing them). Your attempt actually shouldn't have worked at all, since [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)'s `getuser` doesn't take arguments but merely returns the user login name. And `email@gmail.com` isn't even a valid variable name (you didn't put it into quotes)...