# Reading and parsing email from Gmail using C#, C++ or Python

Tags: c#, python, email, gmail

I have to do a Windows application that from times to times access a Gmail account and checks if there is a new email. In case there is, it must read the email body and subject (a simple text email, without images or attachments).

Please, do not use paid libs, and in case of any other libs used, give the download path.

And I need the email body and subject only. So if the long and complex message that comes from Gmail could be parsed and only two strings containing the subject and the body, it would be perfect.

Finally, I only have to get the new messages arrived since the last execution. So the read messages could be marked as "read" and only the new ones (marked as "new") are considered.

The code can be written in Python or C++, but I prefer it in C#.

Related question:

- [Properly formatted example for Python iMAP email access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315362/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This prints the subject and body of unseen messages, and marks those messages as seen.

```
import imaplib
import email

def extract_body(payload):
    if isinstance(payload,str):
        return payload
    else:
        return '\n'.join([extract_body(part.get_payload()) for part in payload])

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
conn.login("user", "password")
conn.select()
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
try:
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                subject=msg['subject']                   
                print(subject)
                payload=msg.get_payload()
                body=extract_body(payload)
                print(body)
        typ, response = conn.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Seen)')
finally:
    try:
        conn.close()
    except:
        pass
    conn.logout()
```

Much of the code above comes from [Doug Hellmann's tutorial on imaplib](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/imaplib/).

Comment: It really works. I am able to get the subject of unseen messages and mark then as seen. However the get_payload() function does not work properly. I am not able to get the message body. Instead of the body, I get messages like:
[<email.message.Message instance at 0x1005a2488>, <email.message.Message instance at 0x1005a2ea8>]

Comment: @jpnavarini: I added code to handle multi-part messages. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: I wish this worked for me! Doesn't work on my old Mac. Do you need to change anything other than username and password?

Comment: @Dylan: This is no longer working for me either. `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)` is timing out. Not sure what the fix is...

Comment: @unutbu Aaaand, now mine is working. I typed this `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` in the terminal. It said `Connection closed by foreign host` but it allowed my to connect to port 993 at least. :) cheers

Comment: What should I put in payload? I can't figure it out! :/ @unutbu

Comment: @ubuntu google may be preventing you from using your regular credentials using this method. instead of using your regular gmail credentials, I recommend creating a pair of application-specific credentials for this script at https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords ; I also recommend making a really specific name for those credentials. it drives me nuts when I can't remember what one of the records was for.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the many [C# IMAP libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545724/using-c-net-librarires-to-check-for-imap-messages-from-gmail-servers).

Comment: Yes, gmail supports IMAP, but IIRC you need to switch it on. Wouldn't make sense to take any other approach. +1

Comment: As I said, I would like to use a free library. So if you could suggest one. And, if possible, send a simple example code using the library. Don't forget also about the transformation of the long and complex message that comes from Gmail into two simple strings.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are some differences between Gmail-IMAP and IMAPA. For example, due to the fact that Gmail treats folders like labels, the code like the one below doesn't delete message if it's tagged with some other folder:

```
imap_instance.uid('store', uid, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
imap_instance.expunge()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I wanted to add the following link to the Open Source ImapX 2 Library discussion: https://imapx.codeplex.com/ the developers seem to be keeping the project up to date. Great job to those all involved

Answer (score 0):

Google has opened it's Gmail API for accessing your gmail account. You can check a quickstart sample with the basic functionalities at this link:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, Q
# This prints the subject and body of unseen messages, and marks those messages as seen.
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password') as mailbox:
    # *mark_seen param = True by default
    print([(m.subject, m.html or m.text) for m in mailbox.fetch(Q(seen=False), mark_seen=True)])
```

[imap_tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imap_tools/)