# Python-Gmail Email Retreving/downloading

Tags: python, email, download, gmail

I just thought,
would it be possible to make a python script which recives information (emails) from gmail?
e.g. I type in my username and password then it goes to www.google.com/mail/user..... and downloads emails as .txt files for me to read?

[Python 3.1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for : [Reading and parsing email from Gmail using C#, C++ or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792623/reading-and-parsing-email-from-gmail-using-c-c-or-python)